# How to estimate flow paths between contaminant sources and catchment offtake (exposure point) at catchment?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, hydrology

I am trying to estimate flow paths between contaminant sources and the catchment offtake (exposure point) at the catchment.

Can anybody give me some help in how to proceed?

Comment: Please provide some more detail about your project.  What data do you have to work with?  Do you have the Spatial Analyst Extension?  This is normally a raster processing operation, so that extension is necessary, or you will have to use other software.  Do you have a DEM (Digital Elevation Model)?  Please expand your question to include detail about your project, the data, and if you have tried anything so far.  This will allow people to build off what you have done to more specifically answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following model/workflow to get started:

[image]

This very basic model yields drainage basins and streams/ephemeral streams from a digital elevation model (DEM).  You can expand on this to include watersheds and expanded flow analysis if you care to.  From here you should start to see which areas are likely to be affected by point source pollution.

**Resources:**

- [An overview of the Hydrology toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000004w000000)
- [Deriving runoff characteristics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Deriving_runoff_characteristics/009z0000005p000000/)
- [Hydrologic analysis sample applications](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Hydrologic_analysis_sample_applications/009z0000005z000000/)

[image]